# "Float object argument after * must be an iterable, not float" Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python

I'm running  this line of code written with python with input 32 which is taken as a float type and get this error. I'm not exactly sure what it's telling me or how to fix it. Thanks

I've tried changing the input type to string and int but it does not resolve the issue.

```
volume = (r1**2)*h1*(pi)+(1/3)*pi(*height-h1)*((r1**2)+r1*r2+(r2**2))



TypeError: float object argument after * must be an iterable, not float
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `*` before `height` to outside the parentheses.

```
volume = (r1**2)*h1*(pi)+(1/3)*pi*(height-h1)*((r1**2)+r1*r2+(r2**2))
```

`*height` is [unpacking](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558). It requires an iterable (like a list or tuple).

Comment: wow such a simple fix I didn't even notice. Always helps to get a second set of eyes. Thanks so much!!!